# VPS or Cloud Hosting, which is the most suitable for me?

Tags: vps, hosting, cloud

I have an institutional site and an API to communicate a PostgreSQL database with a web system and an application in React Native. The web system, the API, the database, and the institutional site must be hosted. The system is to administer a condominium, so at first it will not have many accesses, but this can increase. For me, would a VPS or Cloud Hosting be better? In case of VPS, what minimum configuration should it have, given the situation?

Comment: A hosted VPS will often be cheaper than cloud hosting, especially for high bandwidth sites, as clouds often charge a lot for bandwidth. Cloud is good if you need great security, scalability, flexibility, great backups, basically enterprise level features and are willing to pay for it. There are cheap cloud instances, especially if your bandwidth and storage needs are modest - an AWS t3.micro with 10GB disk is about $7 per month. AWS Lightsail has some great deals including cheap bandwidth. Digital Ocean is worth considering. You'll need to benchmark to decide resources required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPS is for hosting one to many domains. A cloud is a server you don't own. If you need to host a lot of domains, then a vps is a good choice if you don't want the expense of a dedicated server.  Cloud services can include VPS software or not. IOW, the two the cloud and a vps are not the same thing.  If you only have one domain, or only need one IP, then you don't really need a vps, but if you need access to root, then a vps, in a cloud or not, is the way to go.

Comment: I think VPS will suit me better, how do I choose a good VPS setup?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Generally, vps are sold by the storage space you want. There are other factors too, like how much RAM and how "managed" your vps needs to be. 
If you have just a few domains and not a big requirement for storage (keep in mind a full drive is not as groovy as one-half full drive, and don't forget to save space for backups). 
For software, I'm a big fan of WHM/cPanel, but there are other choices.  Can you do most of the backend work, like installing a firewall, anti-virus, do updates and tweak your settings and zone files?  If so, then you don't need a managed vps.